# I have to add sms.to for sending otp in my django-rest-framework project . I didn't find any python package for that. how can i implement this?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In this project, I have to send opt to the user. I have to use 'sms.to', can someone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: ok so you want to send otp to the register user.. so can you tell me OTP will go by email or phone number?

Comment: @TanveerAhmad by phone

Comment: brother then you have to use twilio

Comment: @TanveerAhmad, brother client told me to use sms.to .... he has purchased a package in sms.to